# Reactor Kafka with Netty Fully Reactive

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I came across this quora post which kind of hit me? Am I going to have problem with my fully reactive project?

https://www.quora.com/Why-do-so-many-developers-dislike-Apache-Kafka

The main point is that kafka consumers are blocking whenever they are trying to subscribe to a topic, even though they only subscribe to a topic initially or whenever there's a disconnect.
And this may lead to potentially lots of blocking calls which use up the limited no of thread pools.

Can someone please shed a light and offer a way to get around this? I am using Reactor-kafka library, ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate.

Comment: You're still limited by the base Kafka protocols regardless of which higher library you use...

Comment: yes i know, but surely whoever wrote the reactive kafka library have thought of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Reactor kafka would run any blocking code on side threads in order not to block the main event loop which shouldn't be blocked (as everyone knows) and with **[timeouts](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/blob/5701756df6e0a4dc3f376f35ba3dbe574c783458/src/main/java/reactor/kafka/receiver/ImmutableReceiverOptions.java#L45)** you can set the ReceiverOptions so that these blocking calls shall hopefully not starve the other threads.

Here's the [KafkaReceiver](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/blob/master/src/main/java/reactor/kafka/receiver/internals/DefaultKafkaReceiver.java) implementation which wraps the Kafka consumer and as I see schedulers are used everywhere to ensure just that. Plus [here's](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/blob/8d14541bab6a8d41396bc2ef94ebc8e52a7f40e7/src/main/java/reactor/kafka/receiver/internals/DefaultKafkaReceiver.java#L433) where the KafkaConsumer is created and it's created in `run()` method from runnable.